# Redirect single page http to https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect a single page from http to https using .htaccess, but I keep getting a redirect loop error.

Code:

```
Redirect /secureform.html https://www.example.com/secureform.html
```

However, I keep getting a "this webpage has too many redirects" error. How do I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secureform\.html$ https://www.example.com/secureform.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The rewriteRule can be written more generically, which might make it more portable by using `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` for example: `RewriteRule ^secureform\.html$ %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=301]`

Answer (score -3):

I have tried this and it works for me:

```
Redirect permanent /secure https://www.example.com
```