# htaccess - redirect single html page to https

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect single html page to https. For this I've tried [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152914/redirect-single-page-http-to-https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16152914/1833314)  this also.
but it's not working.

my web url format is `http://www.example.com/api/test.html` , 
I need to convert this **test.html** page to `https://www.example.com/api/test.html`

any help please.

Comment: @Rikesh I just checked it. and yes , it's off. so informing server administratot to open this. Thanks for Your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP

```
if (!preg_match("/https/i", $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])) {
    header("Location: https://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] ."/" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+api/test\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```